# Problem with setting header "Content-Type" in uploading file with HttpClient4

Tags: java, file-upload, httpclient

I'm trying to a upload file (or multiple files) to my servlet, which is using Apache file-upload to handle and get post-ed files.

All is going well and the file is send and recieved, when I use the following code.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myservice.com/servlet");

MultipartEntity entity2 = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File("C:/docOut.pdf"));
entity2.addPart("file", fileBody);
post.setEntity(entity2);

HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
```

But when I try to set my own "Content-Type" to recommended one (or the one only accepted with the Apache file-upload library) with uploading file:

```
post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

My servlet doesn't get any of files and throws an exeption:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:931)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:349)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
at com.myservice.server.filerep.action.FileUploadFormAction.execute(FileUploadFormAction.java:54)
at com.myservice.server.filerep.web.FileRepServlet.doGet(FileRepServlet.java:34)
at com.myservice.server.filerep.web.FileRepServlet.doPost(FileRepServlet.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

I'm aware that POST requests with the uploading file shouldn't contain boundary "elements" in request to determine the order of uploaded byte chunks, but I thought HttpClient will add all the needed information to my request (similar as when I don't specify content-type).

My questions are:

1. Why did adding "Content-Type" break my request? Shouldn't HttpClient add boundary elements to content-type defined by me?
2. Should I explicity set "Content-Type" to my request or let the library handle it?
3. If I can set `Content-Type` explicity could you provide a code snippet?
4. If I can explicity set Content-Type why should I use and prefer "multipart/form-data" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when it comes to POSTing to some forms?

PS: I found somehow related questions, but not addressing my problem:

[ContentType issue with commons-upload and httpcomponent client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014633/contenttype-issue-with-commons-upload-and-httpcomponent-client)

[How can I See the content of a MultipartForm request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720077/how-can-i-see-the-content-of-a-multipartform-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have form data enctype, you must follow the rules as specified in [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388). Data in multipart message are treated as entity so each entity must have a header (with `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Type`, etc.) and a boundary.

As to answer question 1, the RFC states:

> As with all multipart MIME types, each
> part has an optional "Content-Type",
> which defaults to text/plain.

For 2), As mentioned, every multipart message must have an header, so you have to specify your Content-Type (if you're not fully using HttpClient library features).

For 3) and 4) RFC states:

> If multiple files are to be returned
> as the result of a single form entry,
> they should be represented as a
> "multipart/mixed" part embedded within
> the "multipart/form-data".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link - after I read it and do few tests with HttpClient i found what I was doing wrong: when setting "Content-Type" i need to provide boundary (post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=randomBoundaryNotInAnyOfParts") also i need to provide SAME boundary to MultipartEntity or else HttpClient will insert between parts his own random boundary. Tnx for pointing me the right way :).

Comment: I am in the same situation but didn't understand what to do. I was hoping that the MultipartEntity would tell the HttpPost object that it is multipart, form data and have some boundary, and I wouldnt set content type by myself.

I didn't quite get how to provide boundaries to the entities - the MultipartEntity doesn't have a method like setBoundary.

Or, how to get that randomly generated boundary to specify it in addHeader by myself - no getBoundary methor either...

Answer (score 0):

to fedd/ the class which inserts randomly generated boundary is HttpClient, not HttpPost. so you should look at methods for HttpClient

Comment: sorry, i was to add comment for fedd, but clicked wrong button :(