# How to upload images to tumblr api?

Tags: java, api, tumblr

I found this [Tumblr API - how to upload multiple images to a Photoset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878662/tumblr-api-how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-a-photoset) link shows how to do it.But I still cannot figure out how to realize it in java.I have file path of this image,I also finished authentication.What should I do to upload it to tumblr?

I also found [Posting an image to the Tumblr API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365036/posting-an-image-to-the-tumblr-api) .But I don't think `URLEncoder.encode(bytes.toString(), enc);` can do the job.

Comment: I think your question is a more generic one, about uploading files with HTTP POST with Java. Try searching that subject