# Upload file to Solr with HttpClient and MultipartEntity

Tags: file-upload, solr, httpclient, multipart

httpclient, httpmime 4.1.3

I am trying to upload a file through http to a remote server with no success.

Here's my code:

```
    HttpPost method;
    method = new HttpPost(solrUrl + "/extract");
    method.getParams().setParameter("literal.id", fileId);
    method.getParams().setBooleanParameter("commit", true);

    MultipartEntity me = new MultipartEntity();
    me.addPart("myfile", new InputStreamBody(doubleInput, contentType, fileId));

    method.setEntity(me);
    //method.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse hr = httpClient.execute(method);
```

The server is Solr.

This is to replace a working bash script that calls `curl` like this,

`curl http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=bububu&commit=true -F myfile=@bububu.doc`

If I try to set "Content-Type" "multipart/form-data", the receiving part says that there's no boundary (which is true):

`HTTP Status 500 - the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

If I omit this header setting, the server issues an error description that, as far as I discovered, indicates that the content type was not multipart [2]:

`HTTP Status 400. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ([doc=null] missing required field: id).`

This is related to [1] but I couldn't determine the answer from it. I was wondering,

> I am in the same situation but didn't understand what to do. I was hoping that the MultipartEntity would tell the HttpPost object that it is multipart, form data and have some boundary, and I wouldnt set content type by myself. I didn't quite get how to provide boundaries to the entities - the MultipartEntity doesn't have a method like setBoundary. Or, how to get that randomly generated boundary to specify it in addHeader by myself - no getBoundary methor either...

[1] [Problem with setting header "Content-Type" in uploading file with HttpClient4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212404/problem-with-setting-header-content-type-in-uploading-file-with-httpclient4)

[2] http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Updating-the-index-with-a-csv-file-td490013.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspicious of

```
method.getParams().setParameter("literal.id", fileId);
method.getParams().setBooleanParameter("commit", true);
```

In the first line, is `fileId` a string or file pointer (or something else)? I hope it is a string. As for the second line, you can rather set a normal parameter.

---

I am trying to tackle the `HTTP Status 400`. I dont know much Java (or is that .Net?)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: 1) it is a string, 2) tried that either. this is Java and Apache HttpClient

Comment: Could you print the request string being generated?

Comment: You were totally correct about the problem location. It was in how I set the parameters. They should be in a URL, not set as POST or Multipart parameters.

So I did it like this,

`fileId = URLEncoder.encode(fileId, "UTF-8"); method = new HttpPost(solrUrl + "/update/extract?literal.id="+fileId+"&commit=true");`